# VBA - Convert Excel Table to Text in Word

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

My objective is to convert an Excel table to text

I have copied the range in Excel and then comes the following code...

'    ===============
'    CONVERT IN WORD
'    ===============

```
Dim wApp As Word.Application
Dim wDoc As Word.Document

Set wApp = CreateObject("word.application")
wApp.Visible = True

Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Add

With wDoc.Content
    .PasteExcelTable False, False, False
    .Tables(1).Select
    .Rows.ConvertToText Separator:=wdSeparateByDefaultListSeparator, NestedTables:=True
End With
```

This last line of code fails throwing run time error 5907... There is no table at this location.

---

This is a macro that was written in Word itself and runs without error after I manually paste into Word but I want to use the above solution as I am also running code on this table in Excel before bringing it into Word and trying to use one routine versus two.

```
With Selection
    .WholeStory
    .PasteExcelTable False, False, False
    .Tables(1).Range.Select
    .Rows.ConvertToText Separator:=wdSeparateByDefaultListSeparator, _
        NestedTables:=True
End With
```

Thanks for your help... grinnZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
With wDoc.Content
    .PasteExcelTable False, False, False
    .Tables(1).Rows.ConvertToText _
                Separator:=wdSeparateByDefaultListSeparator, _
                NestedTables:=True
End With
```

Comment: Your solution works. I would vote up if I had rep. Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to upvote, but if it solves your problem then clicking the checkmark to flag as an answer will help anyone else who has the same problem.